# Lagrange's theorem intuition

Tags: group-theory, intuition, equivalence-relations

I cannot grasp the intuition behind |G|/|H|=[G:H]. Starting from the equivalence relation x~y if and only if x^(-1)*y is in H, I can see a sort of division, but in my mind, the equivalence relation translates into: [G:H]/|G| = |H| (the number of equivalence classes, represented by y, divided by the cardinal of G, represented by x gives the cardinal of H).
Where is the analogy flawed?

Comment: It would be different from the first equality if I just multiply by |G| the second one. Whilst the first and true equality states that the division of |G| and |H| is the number of equivalence classes, my intuitive equality would give the product of |G| and |H| to be the same, which is false.

Comment: Thank you, you're right. I missed that divising line in the first equality. Then it is clear: what you see in your mind is wrong: in finite cases (like this one, which is just Lagrange's Theorem), the sum of the number of elements in different (and in fact pairwise disjoint) equivalence clases is the total number of elements in the whole set, and since in *this case* all the equivalence classes have the same number of elements as $\;H\;$ , you get $\;[G:H]|H|=|G|\;$ .

Comment: This title is very misleading. I suggest you change it to something that suggests Lagrange's Theorem.

Comment: Allright. I'll change it.